# Cordova/PhoneGap add plugin fails

Tags: cordova, plugins

When I try to add plugin for android platform, it's throwing the below error, not sure what's wrong, previously adding plugin was working fine..

Also tried after updating cordova to 3.4.0

***Error: Failed to fetch package information for org.apache.cordova.file***

```
> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.file" via plugin registry
**Error: Failed to fetch package information for org.apache.cordova.file**
    at C:\Users\hank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src
\registry\registry.js:32:20
    at Request.cb [as _callback] (C:\Users\hank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordo
va\node_modules\plugman\src\registry\registry.js:251:9)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\hank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modu
les\plugman\node_modules\request\index.js:148:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (C:\Users\hank\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\request\index.js:257:10)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

`cordova add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git`

If this doesn't work, try deleting the contents of your plugin folder and run the above command again.

Comment: You need to add plugin there, cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media.git